# Applying changes to xorg.conf without restarting

Tags: xorg

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and making some changes to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. I now need to restart X server to apply the changes, but I don't want to restart my machine.

I know restarting the display manager (eg. lightdm) will sometimes work, is this the best way to do it?

Comment: I know for certain that the GDM display manager restarts X after you log out of a session. I would guess other display managers do as well as its a good way to clean up the environment.

Comment: I wish can hot reload without restarting xorg. Some settings can be online adjusted by xinput and xrandr utilities, but not all can.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this from the command line:

```
sudo restart lightdm
```

or alternatively

```
 sudo service lightdm restart
```

I am not sure what will happen if you are already running X,  but it should restart it, so better close out all windows first.

See [Restart X Server Ubuntu 12.04 Without Rebooting](http://ubuntuportal.com/2012/05/restart-x-server-ubuntu-12-04-without-rebooting.html) and [How to kill and to start the X server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131051/how-to-kill-and-to-start-the-x-server) for more information.

Always a good idea to keep a copy of any configuration file before you modify it so that you can easily restore it if something goes awry.

Comment: The second option terminated all my opened applications and logged out. It's pretty close to restart. So make sure you save everything...

Answer (score 2):

1. Backup your original xorg.conf
2. Make the changes you want in xorg.conf
3. Execute the command: killall X
4. Ubuntu will reload the X for you with new xorg.conf

Answer (score 1):

Logging out of the session will cause X to restart with most display managers.

As suggested by someone else, you could also try `sudo restart lightdm`, however, depending on your display manager this might also be `sudo restart gdm` or `sudo restart kdm` (you used lightdm as an example, so I'm assuming that's what you've got; just wanted to cover all the bases).

**EDIT:** Removed `Ctrl + Alt + Backspace` as someone pointed out that this has been disabled in Ubuntu. May work for people on different distros who find this thread.

Comment: I think Ctrl-Alt-Backspace has been disabled by default in Ubuntu for some time now...

Comment: It's ok to refer to others specifically instead of generically as `someone` :-) E.g., `@jasonwryan` or `@Levon`. No biggie, just a suggestion (and what I've seen as common practice over on SO)

Comment: `Ctrl + Alt + Backspace` isn't disabled "by Ubuntu", but was disabled by default in X, I believe back with the 1.5 release. One needs to explicitly enable it, so it's probably rare these days. If you want it to work, search `man xorg.conf` for the "DontZap" option.